# Is it safe, is it worth while to install WIndows 10 Mobile insider preview?

Tags: insider-preview

Is it safe to install the insider preview on my Lumia 950, and is it worth it? What will I gain from it? New features? and of course New bugs?

I have been a Windows Insider for PC since the release Of Windows 10 so I am well aware of the risks of bugs and instability, but are the gains worth the trouble?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 3):

Since you already have the 950 (and as a result Windows 10) the only reason to subscribe to Insider Preview is to have the latest features as soon as possible. These feature most of the times are minor improvements to the UI etc.

If you have the patience though and not subscribe, you'll get these features 2-4 months after the Insider Preview subscribers do. As you already said the insider preview comes with bugs.

So the gains are:

- *Minor* features

The troubles are:

- Possible *small* bugs
- Possible *huge* bugs

So to answer your question:

> Are the gains worth the trouble?

The answer is **NO** unless you find it extremely important to have these minor features as soon as possible.